# Excel VBA: Loop for setting dynamic named ranges in worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, named-ranges

I need to loop trough each worksheet in my workbook and set dynamic named ranges in each one of them, except worksheet Summary Report.
I need to name the ranges with the worksheet name and "Close".

I currently have this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DefineNamedRanges()

    Dim WSheet As Worksheet

    Dim ShtName As Variant

    For Each WSheet In Worksheets

        ShtName = WSheet.Name

        If ShtName <> "Summary Report" Then

            WSheet.Names.Add Name:=ShtName & "Close", _
                RefersTo:="=OFFSET(ShtName!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(ShtName!$A$2:$A$1048576),COUNTA(ShtName!$2:$2))"

        End If

    Next WSheet

End Sub
```

This code creates the ranges and names them as I want.
When I open the Name Manager, it seems that the ranges are not referring to anything. 
It is like solely the names are created, but not the ranges themselves.

[image: Names Manager]

Comment: You need to move `ShtName` *outside* the quotation marks in the `RefersTo` and concatenate with `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ShtName` is *within* the quotation marks, it's no longer a variable, but the text `"ShtName"`, as evidenced by your screen shot.

Move all instances of `ShtName` *outside* the quotation marks and concatenate with `&`. You should probably add single quotes as well around the sheet name.

Change

```
"=OFFSET(ShtName!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(ShtName!$A$2:$A$1048576),COUNTA(ShtName!$2:$2))"
```

to

```
"=OFFSET('" & ShtName & "'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('" & ShtName & "'!$A$2:$A$1048576),COUNTA('" & ShtName & "'!$2:$2))"
```